# Is it possible to render empty <div style="width:50%"> </div> with CSS in xHTML strict 1.0 without setting width and height in pixels?

Tags: css, xhtml, xhtml-1.0-strict

Is it possible to render empty `<div style="width:50%">    </div>` with CSS in xHTML strict 1.0 without setting width and height in absolute values and not adding `&nbsp;` inside?
Targets are IE7-8, FF 3.x

Can I somehow render empty div if I want it to get 50% width and variable height?

Comment: In a standards compliant browser, an empty div without vertical padding has zero height. What do you expect to be rendered?

Comment: I expect to be rendered a 50% empty space before next float:left; display:inlide; element

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Add some padding to the `DIV` so that even if there is absolutely nothing between the opening and the closing tags, you still see something.

```
<div style="width:50%; padding:10px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 34):

I'd personally go for `<div style="min-height:1px;width:50%"></div>.` That way any non empty divs will not get unwanted padding as in the other answer.

Obviously, in a separate CSS file it would be `div { min-height:1px; width:50% }`

Comment: IMHO this is the best xbrowser solution

Answer (score 9):

Or give it one non-breaking space (&nbsp;)

Comment: I had to make this lowercase

Answer (score 2):

My Experience:

In addition to what user 'random' answered, i need to add space (&nbsp;) to make it work
Hope this helps!

```
    <div style="width:50%; padding:10px;">&nbsp;</div>
```